# What can be done about duplicate notifications in the Stack Overflow & Stack Exchange iOS apps?

Tags: support, notifications, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

I have both the [Stack Exchange](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8) iOS app (used for all stack sites other than Stack Overflow) and the [Stack Overflow](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-overflow/id1155618808?mt=8) app. I get duplicate push notifications from both apps.

When clicking on SO notifications from the SO app, it keeps me in the SO app (which is a really nice app, so I don’t necessarily want to delete it) whereas non-SO notifications always push me to the SE app.

Is there a way to set the SO app to only be for SO notifications? How were the two apps designed to be used in unison without having duplicate notifications?

---

**UPDATE**: The intention was for notifications to be routed to the apps separately but this doesn’t work for me! Does it work for others?

[SO Blog Post: App Launch](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/)

> If you decide to download both apps, your notifications will be split between the two. Your Stack Overflow notifications will appear in the Stack Overflow app, and all other Stack Exchange notifications will appear in the Stack Exchange app.

Comment: Do you receive the SO notifications on the SE app as well? In that case, a temporary workaround would be disabling notifications for the SO app. But then again, I don't really know why there is a second app instead of improving the one app that already exists. If I could, I'd close the new app as a duplicate of the first. ;)

Comment: @NVZ Removing the SO notifications is a good temporary fix but I’m curious how the creators of the SO app expect users of SO + other stack sites to use both apps efficiently. Possibly the SO app is supposed to be a stand alone for those that use SO exclusively of other stack sites and people who use multiple stack sites are expected to use the SE app? Regardless I don’t understand why I don’t have the option to route all SO notifications to that app and all other notifications to the SE app.

Comment: "Why is there an SO app at all" is a big question and might need a new meta. lol. You can see all notifications on SE app. But then manually open the SO app to browse SO stuff if you reaaally like the new app.

Comment: @NVZ I looked into your question further (why didn’t I google this earlier...sorry) and found the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/) about the app launch which answers your question and explains how notifications are SUPPOSED to work. See updated answer.

Comment: @NVZ thanks for the link. I've flagged to migrate to SO Meta as this mainly pertains to the SO app.